# addTarget not working for a few seconds

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am creating a button programatically and adding a target. When I run the button is not responsive for a few seconds (like 5 or 7) and then it starts working. I can't figure out why this would be. All of my network connections are on background threads and the button is created after all the network stuff is finished anyway and in no point does the rest of the UI lock up. It just seems to be this one button. Any ideas of what could be going on? The code is pretty standard, I just feel like every post should have a little bit of code in it.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(getComments)
                                                 name:@"Update"
                                               object:nil];
...
}
-(void)getComments{
    WrapperView *wrapper = (WrapperView*)self.parentViewController;
    [Comment getCommentsForLunchPk:wrapper.lunch.pk WithCompletionBlock:^(bool success, NSArray *cmnts) {
        if(success){
            comments = cmnts;
            [self updateCommentView];
        }
    }];
}
-(void)updateComments{
   ...
   UIButton *delete = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(246, 4, 55, 55)];
   delete.tag = comment.pk;
   [delete addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteComment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [delete setTitle:@"x" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [commentView addSubview:delete];
   ...
}
-(void)deleteComment:(UIButton*) button{
    NSLog(@"delete ");
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it's not good idea to [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:]. Use [UIButton buttonWithType:] instead.

Comment: Where is your commentView creation and where is call [self updateComments] situated?

Comment: Try calling the updateComments function on the mainthread.

Comment: Updated. I am pretty sure completion block are called on the main thread. The button is being created it's almost as if the gesture recognizer isn't immediately enabled.

Comment: How long does it take for the notification named `update` to be posted, and on what thread (or queue or operation) is **that** work being done? Have you **checked** that the completion block is executing on the main thread?

Comment: It's pretty fast, not even noticeable. How do you test which thread something is running on? It just seems to me that if the button is being created then the button should also be working.